# Customized keyGenerator in @Cacheable Doesn't Support Reactive Type

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, reactive-programming, spring-data-redis

Project is using `spring-boot:3.2.0` and `spring-boot-starter-data-redis-reactive:3.2.0`, and the whole project is implemented in a reactive manner using `webFlux`.

For service methods I want to cache the result by adding the following annotation:

```
@Cacheable(cacheNames = "Something",
 keyGenerator = "userKeyGenerator", unless = "#result == null")
```

The default keyGenerator works fine, which can return method parameters etc.

However, for some methods I would like to add user credentials to the cache key as well, for example:

```
public class UserKeyGenerator extends SimpleKeyGenerator {
    @Override
    public Object generate(Object target, Method method, Object... params) {
        Object[] args = Arrays.copyOf(params, params.length + 1);
        Mono<SecurityContext> context = ReactiveSecurityContext.getContext();
        return context.map(context -> {
            args[params.length] = context.getAuthentication().getCredentials();
            return generateKey(args);
        });
    }
}
```

Ideally what I would like to achieve is some cache keys following the format:

```
"Something::SimpleKey \[...(method params), \*userCredentials\]"
```

just adding another element at the end of the cache and remaining part which contains method params is the same as default one.

The problem is the returned key is `"Something::MonoMapFuseable"` which basically makes the key itself not explainable.

How to fix this issue? I am pretty new to `webFlux` and `redis`, any ideas are more than welcome!

Comment: Can you try using `ReactiveSecurityContext.getContext().block()` to get the actual object and return whatever key you like? I think it's because items in reactive are evaluated at a different time, the key is not available when you try to add it in the cache

Comment: it returns error “block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread parallel-2”